# How to save user inputs like in a database?

Tags: javascript, html

Except the fact I am not able to use PHP. I have a single HTML file I can work with. So the only way is JS I think. And I have an "email" user input where the user sets his email and the n he is able to proceed, but I have to save his email first. Any ideas?

Comment: With no server-side language, like PHP, you can't.

Comment: Without PHP there's no way to store the data server side, but you could use localStorage if it will work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: do you have access to anywhere else where you can create a PHP file to send the email address to do using AJAX?

Comment: Be more specific please on where do you want to store the data, if you want to store it server-side, for sure you need some server side platform of whatever u wish ( i.e java, node.js, ruby, etc,,, anything where you manage to handle http requests - it doesnt necessarely needs to be php) - if you just want to store it locally, well, use localStorage or old fashioned cookies

Comment: Peter: yes, I think. But I'm afraid using localStorage would not be a wise method since I can't really operate on the server, nor the host, I can just modify the simple html file, like on some blog page.

Comment: I'm not sure if cookies would be a good idea either. Think of it, storing a bunch of emails in a cookie.

Comment: same with localStorage for u then... any user can access localStorage

Comment: it seems you really want a server-side platform, as i said, look for anything you could use, i.e a simple node.js server would solve the problem

Comment: if you dont want http get/posts, you can even use websockets, all you need is some server side platform, there is no other way

Comment: How long term does the storage need to be? How secure does it need to be? Your description says you only have access to the HTML which screams data elements to me, but then you go on to say that you're concerned about using cookies security-wise, which makes HTML not even an option.

Comment: Well... I might have got confused then. I will try to explain this now. Imagine I have a login page where users have to fill only their name. Once they filled out the username input (or email, it doesn't matter now), they should be able to log in. The only thing I want to do is to store their login informations like when did they login, from what platform, and what kind of name/email. I don't really need password field since it's a public thing.

Comment: Is it a proper form that they use to login (synchronous), or are you doing it using AJAX (asynchronous)?

Comment: I can use both. The only thing that is forbidden is PHP / mysql method.

Comment: Alright, so long as you don't have to navigate to new pages, I edited my answer to include an example of how to do a very simple example using jquery based javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to save the element in a short term way you can use javascript and the HTML5 data element to save the email as an element of the current page. It is very temporary storage, but is the best you're going to get.

Edit:
Here's how you can do this using jQuery based javascript.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="email">
<input type="button" id="emailButton">
<div id="data_div"></div>
```

jQuery Javascript:

```
function retrieveEmail() {
    var email = $('#data_div').data("email");
    // do something with the email variable as needed here
    // here's an example of retrieving it to send it to the server
    var paramStr = "email=" + email;

    $.ajax({
        url: './your_server_file_here',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: paramStr,
        success: function(data) {
           callBack(data);
    });
}

function callBack(data) {
    // do something with information passed back from the server after you sent the data to the server (you didn't say you needed to do this, but here's where it should be done)
}

function storeEmail() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $('#data_div').data("email", email);
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#emailButton').click( function() {
        storeEmail();
    });
});
```

Edit: I know you already accepted this answer, but it struck me that HTML5 also includes another way to do this and it may provide the increase in power and flexibility that you're looking for. The HTML5 storage element can do pretty much the same thing as the data element except that it can persist and be accessed by other pages from the same domain either until the browser is closed (unlimited amount of data in the sessionStorage) or indefinitely (5mb of data in the localStorage). For implementation details and a greater understanding see [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Be advised though, the HTML5 storage element is only available in HTML5 compatible browsers and should not be used if you fear your user base won't be using a modern browser. The HTML5 Data element will work even in older browsers, so it does have that advantage.

Comment: And is there a way to pass that email from the storage? Any way. The thing is I really need to store user credentials.

Comment: @egyeneskanyar You can pass it around within the same page using AJAX, but to other pages you have to pass it to the server or put it in a cookie, there is no other way.

Comment: May I ask what can I do with the stored e-mail furthermore? Or I should ask, what do you suggest? Is there any way to pass it to some kind of database, or a php page that will be able to process it?

Comment: @egyeneskanyar Yeah calling the retrieveEmail function above will store it back into the var email. From there you could pass it to anywhere you need to by doing an ajax call. I will add a simple example of that.

Comment: Oh, and with the ajax call I can just use my external PHP file to process the info. I guess. It is not a problem to use an outer file as long as I can call it via this html file & I can pass it the value.

Comment: @egyeneskanyar yes, though being able to pass it to that PHP file makes storing it in the data element kind of pointless. I added the example ajax call. The success part is probably unnecessary unless you need to do something with data based back to your page from the server after.

Comment: Thank you! I would really vote you up more if I could!

Comment: @egyeneskanyar Hey I'm glad that helped, I just added one additional alternative solution. It's incredibly powerful and pretty much exactly what you want, but it only works in HTML5 capable browsers, so only use it if you know your user base will be on modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You could always use Javascript to create a text file where you can save information...

Comment: Most browsers aren't going to let you do this by default as it's a massive security risk. ActiveX in ie browsers can do something similar and there are other tools available, but the end user has to agree to install them first. I don't think this is a good idea.